# And another FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream,

Tags: nginx, fastcgi, php

having some issues with 'file not found' or FastCGI sent in stderr.

From what I have searched and researched about the issue it's due to the fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME not being able to locate the file. I've tried so many different combinations with the same result each time.

Here's my nginx.conf if anyone has any ideas it's much appreciated.

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  4;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;

pid        /run/nginx.pid;

events {
worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type  application/octet-stream;

log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

sendfile        on;

keepalive_timeout  60;

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

index   index.php index.html index.htm;

server {
    listen  127.0.0.1:8080;
    root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
    location / {
    }

    error_page  404              /404.html;
    location = /40x.html {
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
    }

location ~ \.php$ {
  root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
  fastcgi_split_path_info  ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
  fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
  fastcgi_index  index.php;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
  include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
}
}


server {
listen       443;

ssl                  on;
ssl_certificate      /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;

ssl_session_timeout  5m;

ssl_protocols  SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1;
ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

location / {
root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
index  index.php index.html index.htm;
}

location ~* ^/phpMyAdmin/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ { root /usr/share/;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
  root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
  fastcgi_split_path_info  ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
  fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
  fastcgi_index  index.php;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
  include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
}
}
}
```